# Execution fail after moving MainActivity.java in Subfolder

Tags: java, android, main-activity

I am currently working on my Android project. Like the title reads I moved my MainActivity.java file into my Activitys package, I did this because a friend of mine suggested me this to reasons of overview. Now I am getting the following error Code after launching, build and install works finde.

My project can be viewed at: https://github.com/SchoolGuy/GCFunde

```
02-17 19:39:24.890  16607-16607/de.noname.enno.gcfunde E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.noname.enno.gcfunde, PID: 16607
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2483)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2271)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1034)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:744)
            at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
            at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1180)
            at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:757)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15695)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4981)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2209)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1943)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1126)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6041)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:557)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.
02-17 19:39:28.163  16607-16607/de.noname.enno.gcfunde D/Process﹕ killProcess, pid=16607
02-17 19:39:28.173  16607-16607/de.noname.enno.gcfunde D/Process﹕ com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:138 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Would be great if you could help me. I am working by the way with IntelliJ 15.0.2 and I did already a Invalidate Cache and Restart. As far as I can see I think the problem is not directly in a class of mine.

Thanks in advance,
School_guy

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a `ListView` issue - probably your `getView` method returns `null` instead of an actual View object. Check your ListAdapter implementation and be sure to never return null in the `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method.

As I can see from your code in the `GeocacheListAdapter.java`, the `if` statement is wrong - the check should be if `(convertView == null)` instead of `if(convertView != null)`

```
if (convertView == null) {
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            //...
}
```

Comment: That`s right, just saw the code and was gonna write back to you. If convertView is null, you have to inflate a view and return it

Comment: Ok, is there a way to avoid recreating parts of a listView element that are the same or just skip recreating an element? Because e.g. when this listView has 15000 elements this wont be fun for the user.

Comment: The current maximum I think will be around 200000 elements in this listView in worst case.

Comment: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html - here is an explanation. I think they are explaining it pretty well in this article.

Comment: Basically with the ViewHolder pattern you create new views only when there are no views to recycle. Thus you get smoothness and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Update your activity tag for the MainActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml file with the new package naming.